# Can't get rid of extra spaces in java

Tags: java

I have extra spaces for example "-     -     -    -" That I'm trying to remove... I tried using regex "\s+" as well as writing my own function.

```
System.out.println(test.removeExtraSpaces("-   -   -  "));
System.out.println(test.removeExtraSpaces("-   -   -  "));
```

and my results are

```
- - -
-   -   -
```

The first one I physically typed out the "spaces" with 3 of them in between each dash and the second one is from an import file. I think the problem I'm having is that they're not "real" spaces or a space with different unicode or something but I don't know how to remove them.

I started off using regex but that didn't work and I tried this which results in the image

```
public String removeExtraSpaces(String s){
    s.trim();
    String newString = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++){
        if(s.charAt(i) != ' '){
            newString = newString + s.charAt(i);
        }
        else{
            if(s.charAt(i + 1) != ' '){
                newString = newString + s.charAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
    newString = newString + s.charAt(s.length()-1);

    return newString.trim();
}
```

Here is the result
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUOKP.png

EDIT: People have been suggesting regex which I've already tried but here is the proof that regex does not work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC1om.png

Comment: Assuming you are using Java 8, can you show us results of `Arrays.toString(yourString.chars().toArray())` so we would see codepoints of characters from your string?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/yRz7B9B.png it's different! but what does that mean?!

EDIT: OHH WITH YOUR HELP AND THE GUY AT THE BOTTOM I GOT IT!! It's unicode 32 and 160. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Character with codepoint `160` is [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) which is not considered as whitespace so `\\s` will not be able to match it. If you want to replace any kind of spaces (including non-breaking one) and any whitespaces (like tabulators `\t` or line breaks `\n` `\r`) try with

```
replaceAll("[\\p{Zs}\\s]+"," ")
```

From http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

> `\p{Zs}` will match any kind of space character

---

**Demo**:

```
char[] arr = { 45, 32, 160, 32, 45, 32, 160, 32, 45, 32, 160 };
String str = new String(arr);
System.out.println("original: \"" + str + "\"");
str = str.replaceAll("[\\p{Zs}\\s]+", " ");
System.out.println("replaced: \"" + str + "\"");
```

Output:

```
original: "-   -   -  "
replaced: "- - - "
```

Comment: I was actually looking for how to... haha accepted!

Answer (score 0):

`\s+` only matches [some](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html) of the Unicode whitespace characters. If you want to cover [all of them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character), adapt your method to check for any of these characters instead of only spaces.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! This is what I was looking for I just didn't know where to start.