# String Split not splitting every space

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to split a string by space. The string is the content of an html page i extracted using Jsoup:

```
Element bodyElement = doc.body();
String bodyText = bodyElement.text();
```

It's quite weird: the string contains the substring "above isn't" in it, but this specific substring isn't splitted.
I used the code:

```
String[] s1 = bodyText.split(" ");
```

also i tried:

```
String[] s1 = bodyText.split("\\s");
```

and i get almost everything rigth (well, there are hundrads of words so i didn't go through each one of them, but as far as i looked) except for the two specific words mentioned.
if it's relevant, the paragraph containing those words is (after removing stop words):

> adding property object using method above isn't possible dot notation, which can only accept literal member name, variable value pointing name.

and after splitting:

```
adding
property
object
using
method
above isn't
possible
dot
notation,
... //all the rest.. 
word.
```

When i tried to copy-paste the paragraph and split- it worked fine so i'm assuming it has to do with the Jsoup parsing, but i'm not sure.

Any ideas why this happens and how to solve? Thanks

Comment: `String[] s1 = string.split(" ");`, where is the variable `string` declared?

Comment: sorry, i edited it now. string is bodyText.

Comment: So what does this tell you? That `above` and `isn't` are not separated by a space, but rather by something else. Do a check of chars in the line to see what it is. Only you have the full data and the full code, and so only you can do this test. One option for a solution is to not split on the space char but rather on any greedy summation of white space `.split("\\s+");`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Eals I also tried "bodyText.split("\\s")", forgot to mention. I'll edit again.

Comment: Probably that space was created via `&nbsp;` (nonbreakable space) which is different than normal space and doesn't belong to `\s` character class.

Comment: Atalia, don't spin your wheels with this question by providing bits of information in dribs and drabs. If you need full help, please improve the question so that it is a full question, one with code that we can run on data that we can get handle to.

Comment: @Pshemo dang, it would seem to me that that *should* be a member of the `\s` character class. :(  Although I believe you that it isn't.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Not quite, whitespaces ware meant to represent characters which split words, but `&nbsp;` is opposite, it joins two words into "one" which will not be separated while displaying it.

Comment: Probably duplicate of [Java doesn't see space in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585683/java-doesnt-see-space-in-string) or [Can't get rid of extra spaces in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461339/cant-get-rid-of-extra-spaces-in-java) (hard to tell without proper [mcve])

Comment: @Pshemo Do you have a suggestion for solving it if that's the case?

Comment: Try splitting on `[\\p{Zs}\\s]` like I already mentioned in questions linked in my previous comment. Let me know if that worked for you.

Comment: @Pshemo thatnks a lot! just saw the link and it worked. Sorry for not posting the full code it was spread around the program and i thought mentioning the html parsing would be enough.

Comment: @Pshemo: many thanks! One of the reasons that I love this site -- I learn new things every day.